# Neo4j not able to find correct java

Tags: java, java-8, neo4j

I am trying to start neo4j on my system by using commnad `neo4j console`. I am getting following error when I run this command

```
Invoke-Neo4j : Could not find java at C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_192\bin\java.exe
At C:\Users\neo4j\neo4j-community-3.5.9\bin\neo4j.ps1:29 char:7
+ Exit (Invoke-Neo4j -Verbose:$Arguments.Verbose -Command $Arguments.Ar ...
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-Neo4j
```

Earlier jre 8.0.192 was installed on my system. I removed it and installed jre 8.0.251 and JDK is installed at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201` . In Environment variable `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\` and In path I have `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\bin;`. Dont know why it is taking 192 version which I already uninstalled. Please help

Comment: Neo4J seems  like it is forcing that version from a config file. Since you already change environmental variables and achieved no positive result, I suggest you go into Neo4J settings/configuration files. I'll search for it on the net also, I'll let you know if I find anything.  Edit : I found this page showing locations of the conf file. https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/

Comment: In case Neo4j is running as service, I've found this page mentioning that after installing a new version of JAVA, you need to run "update-service"  command and then retsart the service.  https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/windows/

Comment: I downloaded neo4j community ediiton 3.5.20. I tried to run twice with failure. After getting the JAVA_HOME variable right on the 3rd time, I was able to run it successfully. My JAVA_HOME = D:\Java\jdk-9.0.4\  . I didn't add anything extra to "path" variable.  Since my java home doesn't have any white spaces, I'm just gonna shoot in the dark and request that you add quotation to your java home path, If you haven't done already.  JAVA_HOME= "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\". Please try it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo - `JAVA_HOMW` instead of `JAVA_HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it successfully, just change the name of the folder to jre1.8.0_192, and then the contents of the folder remain the jre 8.0.251 you downloaded later. In other words, follow its error message and only change the folder name it wants.